# Cross Browser CSS Problem

Tags: css

What would cause styling to be all screwed up on multiple websites (google, stackoverflow, walmart, etc.) on multiple browsers?

Comment: Did you somehow accidentally set a custom stylesheet for your browser(s)? Aaand which browsers?

Comment: Can you see a very bright light? Can you see other people walking slowly towards the light?

Comment: Try pressing the Ctrl and 0 (zero) buttons at the same time. It'll reset your screen to the default size. :)

Answer (score 5):

Across multiple browsers with reputable websites (google, stack, etc.) the only possible explanations are:

1. Your computer's graphics card is buggy.
2. You downloaded a virus/trojan.
3. You (simultaneously for every browser) increased your zoom/text size to a point its breaking the sites.
4. Somebody set us up the bomb.
5. Someone logged / hacked into your computer and for all of your browsers set a bunch of custom user stylesheets with !important and those rules were designed to mess up the styling of your favorite websites. Do you have any enemies?

Look in your browsers program file to see if there are any user stylesheets. Run a spyware sweep for any trojans/viruses. Hopefully that will resolve your issues.

Answer (score 4):

[Magic](http://ex-parrot.com/~pete/upside-down-ternet.html)